# Using if statement to check if numbers exist in xml file?

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have a form which users enter 6 numbers then I'm comparing the entered numbers to xml elements using SimpleXML. If the correct number is found, then it gets stored in a variable($n1 - $n6). The variables are used outside the foreach loop to determine if all 6 numbers are correct, then echos the date and jackpot of the element. This works correctly.

If the numbers entered do not match the xml elements, I want to echo an incorrect result ("Sorry"). However, this part doesn't work as it still echos a date and jackpot which isnt linked the the numbers in xml. It results in a random date and jackpot number which aren't store in the xml file.

How would I ensure when 6 incorrect numbers are entered the result is wrong and echo "Sorry"?

XML:

```
<lottery>
<number>
  <date>7.11.2015</date>
  <num1>2</num1>
  <num2>3</num2>
  <num3>34</num3>
  <num4>43</num4>
  <num5>49</num5>
  <num6>50</num6>
  <jackpot>13156375</jackpot>
</number>
<number>
  <date>08.11.2015</date>
  <num1>11</num1>
  <num2>13</num2>
  <num3>18</num3>
  <num4>25</num4>
  <num5>29</num5>
  <num6>47</num6>
  <jackpot>8842605</jackpot>
</number>
</lottery>
```

PHP:

```
$n1 = false;//make true once we find 1st num
$n2 = false;//make true once we find 2nd num
$n3 = false;
$n4 = false;
$n5 = false;
$n6 = false;

$xml = simplexml_load_file('lottery2.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
            if (isset($_POST['num1']) && isset($_POST['num2'])) {

            foreach ($xml->children() as $record) {
                $n1 = $n1 || $record -> num1 == $num1 || $record -> num2 == $num1 || $record -> num3 == $num1 || $record -> num4 == $num1 || $record -> num5 == $num1 || $record -> num6 == $num1;
                $n2 = $n2 || $record -> num1 == $num2 || $record -> num2 == $num2 || $record -> num3 == $num2 || $record -> num4 == $num2 || $record -> num5 == $num2 || $record -> num6 == $num2;
                $n3 = $n3 || $record -> num1 == $num3 || $record -> num2 == $num3 || $record -> num3 == $num3 || $record -> num4 == $num3 || $record -> num5 == $num3 || $record -> num6 == $num3;
                $n4 = $n4 || $record -> num1 == $num4 || $record -> num2 == $num4 || $record -> num3 == $num4 || $record -> num4 == $num4 || $record -> num5 == $num4 || $record -> num6 == $num4;
                $n5 = $n5 || $record -> num1 == $num5 || $record -> num2 == $num5 || $record -> num3 == $num5 || $record -> num4 == $num5 || $record -> num5 == $num5 || $record -> num6 == $num5;
                $n6 = $n6 || $record -> num1 == $num6 || $record -> num2 == $num6 || $record -> num3 == $num6 || $record -> num4 == $num6 || $record -> num5 == $num6 || $record -> num6 == $num6;

                    if ($n1 && $n2 && $n3 && $n4 && $n5 && $n6) break; //Found match. No need to keep looking

                }//end foreach

                if ($n1 && $n2 && $n3 && $n4 && $n5 && $n6) 
                {
                 echo $record -> date;
                 echo $record -> jackpot;
                }
                else
                {
                 echo "Sorry no winnings";
                }
```

Comment: You conditions are a little messed up here. Lets see what happens `$n1 || $record -> num1 == $num1` will translate to `false || 1 == 2`(for example), which works fine, , until `$n1` is `true`, then `true || 1 == 1`, which is always true since this is a shortcircuite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If think you should consider using arrays instead of bulky `if` statements.

I would do it this way:

- build the list of player numbers and sort it
- for each entry in the XML file:

  - build the list of lottery numbers and sort it
  - compare the player numbers with the lottery numbers, using the sorted arrays

Example code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('lottery2.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");

if(isset($_POST['num1']) && isset($_POST['num2'])) {
  $myList = array($num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, $num5, $num6);
  $result = array();
  $win = 0;

  sort($myList);

  foreach ($xml->children() as $record) {
    for($n = 0; $n < 6; $n++) {
      $result[$n] = (int)$record -> {'num'.($n + 1)};
    }
    sort($result);

    if (match($myList, $result)) {
      echo $record -> date;
      echo $record -> jackpot;
      $win++;
    }
  }
  if($win == 0) {
    echo "Sorry no winnings";
  }
}

function match ($list1, $list2) {
  for($n = 0; $n < 6; $n++) {
    if($list1[$n] != $list2[$n]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: That works great. Just wondering if there is a way to do the if statement outside the foreach loop as "Sorry no winnings" is displayed for every number set that doesn't match as well as the date and jackpot for the correct number match. I've tried break; but that breaks the loop after just the first set is found in the xml file, so any numbers after the first will display incorrectly even if they are correct

Comment: @A.Hollingsworth - You could do that for instance by adding a `$win` counter and displaying the "Sorry no winning" message if `$win == 0` after the loop. (I've updated my answer accordingly.)